# white space between divs, simple HTML

Tags: html, css

I have searched and searched on this site for a solution to this and tried to apply all results too my simple HTML but none have appeared to work.

I'm sure there is a really easy way to do this because at the moment there isn't really any code as  will explain.

I want a simple layout, 3 `div`s. One Main Page `div` containing two horizontal `div`s, I want the two inside `div`s to contain a picture that will be used as the `div` backgrounds enclosed in the Main Page `div`, I can get the backgrounds on but cannot rid the page of the white line, that I'm sure you guys are sick of reading about.

I get the line appearing between "`header`" and "`site`" `div`s. I'm sure this is an easy solution.

I have want to keep the HTML as simple as possible and only plan to have 3 three links that I will put in once the space has gone, as I'm sure I can apply the solution to further `div`s.

I'm also struggling to upload code, please advise

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainwrap">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
            <div id="site">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header{
    width:1080px;
    margin:0;
    height:285;
    background: url(header.jpg);
    float:left; 
}

#site{
    width:1080px;
    margin:0;
    height:480;
    float:left;
    background: url(main.jpg);   
}

#mainwrap{
    width:1280px;
    height:750px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#FFFFCC;
}
```

Many Thanks if someone can post a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're having this problem because of the font size of the container. Set the `line-height` and `font-size` of the container to `0` and the space will disappear.

If it still doesn't fix it, remove any whitespace (including tabs or line breaks) from your HTML so the code blocks are touching each other like so:

```
</div><div>
//   ^^ no space here
```

However, remember that font style declarations will cascade down into the container's children, so be sure to set the `font-size`and `line-height` back to normal inside them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried entering your code in to jsFiddle, but I wasn't able to reproduce the same results you were seeing (with the white lines).   May just be my browser...

However, I think this will help solve your issue.   I've found it's always a good idea to include a CSS Reset in your CSS file.   This gets rid of all those unwanted spaces, margins, and other things that are a pain to work with later.

Try adding the CSS from this site:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Or just Google "CSS Reset" and use any of the CSS samples.    You would add the CSS to your existing CSS...  the reset just makes sure all the margins, padding, etc are set to zero.

Comment: A reset is a *very strong and wide-sweeping* override, and isn't recommended for every project. I think while a reset may (or may not) solve this white space issue, it's probably overkill as a solution

Answer (score 1):

Adding to each element in css file

```
 {overflow: hidden;}
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mr. Brice Said you need to set the smaller line-height as possible to fix the small size to your div of  the source code of your page but take care if in the CSS of your general Body the line-height are diferent, like the example:

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#545454;
    line-height:18px;
}
```

If your div needs a diferent line-height, and font-size to some speciffic section of [website](http://www.empresasite.com.br/) you need to set a class to then, link this:

```
#mainwrap{
   width:1280px;
   height:750px;
   margin:auto;
   background-color:#FFFFCC;
   line-height:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your line between divs disappear you simply add one line of code in your CSS. This line of code is **BORDER** I believe that 1 to 3 pixel border would be ok.

```
#header{border:1px;}
```

You can change the colour of your border the same way as well:

```
#header{border-color:#ffffff;}
```

For example:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainwrap">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="site">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#header{    

border:1px;    

width:1080px;
margin:0;
height:285;`enter code here`
background: url(header.jpg);
float:left;} 

#site{

border:1px;

width:1080px;
margin:0;
height:480;
float:left;
background: url(main.jpg);   }

#mainwrap{

border:1px;

width:1280px;
height:750px;
margin:auto;
background-color:#FFFFCC;}
```